# Xamarin Forms: Specified cast is not valid while adding a global value inside a bindable object: list view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a layout where there is repetitive list of custom entry and when on change of any text List appears, `SuggestedText`, which is just an string observation collection that is initialized during the viewmodal is constructed.

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectLists.ListofLicensePlates}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                      <Frame Margin="0,10,0,10" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                         <Grid Margin="20">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >
                                   <Label Text="Text1" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                                              <AbsoluteLayout>
                                                   <Frame Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Padding="5" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="{StaticResource GrayBorderColor}" CornerRadius="30" HeightRequest="55" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                      <controls:BorderlessEntry 
                                                             TextTransform="Uppercase" Text="{Binding LicensePlate}"
                                                             Index = "{Binding Index}"
                                                             TextChanged ="ShowListView" Completed="ShowListView"
                                                             MaxLength="50" x:Name="Text1" Keyboard="Text" 
                                                             Placeholder="Text1"
                                                                                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="15,70,285,38" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None"
                                                                                     FontFamily="OpenSansRegular" />
                                                  </Frame>
                                                  <ListView BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SuggestedText, Source={x:Reference thispage}}" 
                                                                                  x:Name="LicensePlateListView" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
                                                                                  BackgroundColor="White" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="20,110,269,160" 
                                                                                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None">
                                                       <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                                                                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="16" TextColor="#FF464859"/>
                                                                  </StackLayout>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                   </ListView>
                                            </AbsoluteLayout>
                           </Grid>
                      </Frame>
               </DataTemplate>
          </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

This is how suggested text was created:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
        public LicensePlateListViewModel()
        {
            
        }

        public MyViewModel (MyObject parameters, INavigation navigation)
        {
            MyObjectLists = parameters;
            
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                try
                {
                    FillSuggestText();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    IsBusy = false;
                    Helper.GlobalErrorTrashing(ex);
                }
            });

        }
        private MyObject myObjectLists;
        public MyObject MyObjectLists
        {
            get { return myObjectLists; }
            set { myObjectLists= value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<string> suggestedText;
        public ObservableCollection<string> SuggestedText
        {
            get { return suggestedText; }
            set { suggestedText= value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }


        public void FillSuggestText()
        {
            if (PaidGuestParking.GuestZoneParking.Parkings != null)
            {
                var texts = MyObjectLists.TextList.Select(p => p.Text).ToList();
                foreach(var text in texts ) { 
                    SuggestedText.Add(text);
                }
            }
        }

...
...
...
}
```

And MyObject is something like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public List<TextObject> TextList { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<string> ListofLicensePlates { get; set; }
}
```

And show list view is a simple function that changes `IsVisible` for that particular listview under the entry. It works fine if I statically list all the list view source but whenever I try to do it dynamically adding the content from SuggestedText, I get error before navigating to this page.

```
ex = {System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableLayout+<>c.<.cctor>b__19_4 (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject b) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableLayout.cs:24 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.CreateAndAddCo...
```

I am really stuck at this place please suggest me something, I am also willing to change such that the suggesttext is in MyObjectLists itself so that the suggesttext may be different for different inputs but doing so also prompted same error.

Comment: You do not need to use BindableLayout with ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted,I found that you set `MyObjectLists` as the `BindableLayout.ItemsSource` of `StackLayout`, so the variable `MyObjectLists` should be a collection of `IEnumerable items`.

```
  <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectLists}"  >
```

But from code below included in `MyViewModel.cs` , we can find it looks like a simple Object (`MyObject`).Please recheck it.

```
    private MyObject myObjectLists;
    public MyObject MyObjectLists
    {
        get { return myObjectLists; }
        set { myObjectLists= value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

In addition,if you want to bind the parent's variable `SuggestedText` to the inner `ListView`  , you can try to replace `BindableLayout.ItemsSource` with `ItemsSource` and replace `BindableLayout.ItemTemplate` with `ListView.ItemTemplate`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SuggestedText, Source={x:Reference thispage}}" 
                                                                              x:Name="LicensePlateListView"  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
                                                                              BackgroundColor="White" >
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="16" TextColor="#FF464859"/>
                                            </StackLayout>

                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
```

Or you can also use `StackLayout BindableLayout` instead:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SuggestedText, Source={x:Reference thispage}}" Orientation="Horizontal"  > 
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="16" TextColor="#FF464859"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
```

Note:

If you use `ListView`, remember to add tag `<ViewCell>  </ViewCell>`.

Comment: I have made changes to the code, my bad, I missed to add the list inside. That is exactly what I have.